# Angular 6 Mat-Select does not define user.email through http GET request

Tags: angular, rest, angular-material, mean-stack

I want to make a select with a FormGroup. The data that the user can select from comes through a GET request.

Adminpanel.ts

```
this.userservice.getallusers().subscribe((res: any) =>{
    for (let index = 0; index < res.length; index++) {
      this.users[index] = res[index];
      this.usersemails[index] = this.users[index].email;
      console.log(this.usersemails[index]);
    }

});
```

The data goes through a for loop and gets assigned to array `usersemails[index]`.
The array gets filled up correct.

FormGroup from HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="AddxpForm" (ngSubmit)="addxponSubmit()">
    <mat-form-field class="geo-full-width">
      <input matInput placeholder="Amount of XP" type="number" name="User_xp" formControlName="user_xp">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="User email" name="useremail" fromControlName="useremail">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let useremail of usersemails" [value]="useremail">
        {{useremail}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <button mat-raised-button class="geo-full-width" type="submit" [disabled]="!AddxpForm.valid">Add UserXP</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

The select works also because I can select the emails I get through the HTTP GET request. But when I try to post it again the body email stays `undefined`.

Submit function from ts file

```
addxponSubmit(){
  this.user.email = this.AddxpForm.value.useremail;
  this.user.experience = this.AddxpForm.value.user_xp
  console.log(this.AddxpForm);
  console.log(this.user);
}
```

can someone tell me what I do wrong here ?

Comment: In the code you posted there is a typo at `fromControlName="useremail"`. It should be `formControlName="useremail"`. Don't know if this is your actual error though.

Comment: this worked thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fridoo commented, the problem is the typo, you can check here the form working correctly:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-stack?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts